# Create a 2D list from 1D list

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

I want to create a 2D list from a given 1D list, where each row contains max 2 elements. So let's say
`myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'a',8,9,10,11,'b']`,
the 2D list could look something like
`myList2D = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], ['a'], [8], [9, 10], [11, 'b']]`.

I haven't been able to figure out how to randomize this, I can only create pairs such as [[1,2],[3,4], etc...

Comment: how come the last 2 elements are in pairs of two?

Comment: That is part of the assignment, need to have a few of the elements in pairs of 2 instead of stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'a',8,9,10,11,'b']

myList2 = [[myList.pop(0)]]
twoList = []

#randomly add items to existing lists, remove if already size 2, make new one as part of random choice
for item in myList:
    pos = random.randint(0,len(myList2))
    if pos == len(myList2):
        myList2.append([item])
    else:
        myList2[pos].append(item)
        twoList.append(myList2.pop(pos))

#add remaining items

allList = twoList + myList2
```

I'm assuming that you want to randomly group items into lists of 1 or 2, and you can just replace myList with any list you want.